# how treafik expose cross namespace service in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

My treafik(v2.0) service is in `kube-system` namespce,now I want to expose namespace `dabai-fat` eureka service. This is my expose route config of treafik:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: fat-eureka-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k8s-fat-eureka.example.com`) 
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: eureka
          port: 8761
```

the problem is eureka service in namespace `dabai-fat`.when I check the ingress log:

```
kubectl logs --follow --since=10s traefik-ingress-controller-hx4xd --namespace kube-system
```

the output is:

```
{"ingress":"fat-eureka-route","level":"error","msg":"Cannot create service: service not found kube-system/eureka","namespace":"kube-system","providerName":"kubernetescrd","serviceName":"eureka","servicePort":8761,"time":"2020-02-02T14:35:18Z"}
```

how to specify the `dabai-fat` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IngressRoute and service should be in the same namespace.You need to create IngressRoute in `dabai-fat` namespace where you have `eureka` service and pods.

So your IngressRoute should look like below:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: fat-eureka-route
  namespace: dabai-fat
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k8s-fat-eureka.example.com`) 
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: eureka
          port: 8761
```